# Search if a string contains any value from NSArray of Nsdictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I want to check if my string is contained in any two elements of my NSArray of NSDictionary. Lets say,

```
mystring = @"I love stackoverflow";

array = @{@[id:104, name: @"love", quality: @"stackoverflow"],
@[id:104, name: @"love123", quality: @"stackoverflow"],
@[id:104, name: @"love435", quality: @"stackoverflow"],
@[id:104, name: @"love", quality: @"stackoverflow234"]];
```

In this case I want my predicate to pick out the first element of array as it is sub contained in my string.

I have tried:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ contains[c] SELF.name AND %@ contains[c] SELF.quality",mystring, mystring];

NSArray *filteredArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

PS: 'LIKE' is also not working here.

Comment: Your predicate is ok and works with the data you provided here (after fixing the syntax).

Comment: Surprisingly my Xcode was showing my filteredArray having zero count yesterday. But toady it is working fine. It was working earlier also. It is the correct code. Thanks @Willeke.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine as of now. The syntax that I have provided is correct.